# How to write system(const char * command) output to a file in C++

Tags: c++, windows, ip-address

```
system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig");
```

It generates network related information in the console window. I want to store it into a text file. How to do this?

Comment: What about using `fork()` and a `pipe()`?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Can you please elaborate?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I'm using windows.

Comment: `system("C:\\Windows\\System32\\ipconfig > file.txt");`